# Load an ajax request in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load an AJAX request in a text box. I tried loading the AJAX request using load :-

```
$("#textbox-id").load("file.php");
```

But, it did not work, though the same code worked for a div :-

```
$("#div-id").load("file.php");
```

Is there any such function to load the AJAX request in a textbox? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `jQuery.load()` doesn't do anything AJAX-related. (See the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.) You should use something similar to zzlalani's example: Use `$.ajax()`, then set the textbox value equal to that of the returned data.

Comment: @Jackson see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Whoops! Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the `$.ajax` method? in `success` block get the value out of your response data and set it in your `textbox`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function( data ) {
        $("#textbox-id").val(data);
    },

    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
    }

});
```

OR

```
$.get('file.php', function(data) {
    $("#textbox-id").val(data);
});
```

Comment: thankx...zzzlalani...it worked. And set the `data.value` to `data`